# Hadoop hdfs python, how to get information about avalaible capacity of node?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to get information on the free disk space on VM with Hadoop and the module hdfs, InsecureClient of Python.

The goal would be to have the equivalent of

```
hdfs dfs -df
hdfs dfs -df -h
```

To get the percentage of use of the disk.

[image]

I have this kind of script to connect to Hadoop VM

```
from hdfs import InsecureClient
client = InsecureClient(URL:PORT, user=user)
# 
client = Client(URL:PORT, proxy=proxy)
```

But I can't find a way to retrieve this type of information... Does anyone have an idea ? Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't think WebHdfs exposes this information https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

Comment: Yes that’s what I thought thanks !